# Cron job not running on XAMPP Mac OS X but works otherwise

Tags: php, cron

I am trying to run a cron job using XAMPP on a Mac. I've tried the following commands, but the file isn't created at all. If I run it manually, using `localhost/writer/writer.php`, it works.

I've looked all over Google and SO but nothing address or resonates with my problem. Any help is appreciated.

The commands tried:

```
* * * * * /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/writer/writer.php

* * * * * php /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/writer/writer.php
```

Code being run for test purposes.

```
<?php
$file = 'people.txt';
// Append a new person to the file
$current = "John Smith\n";
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

Note, I've also tried running a sample cron outside of XAMPP, by doing: (It worked).

```
* * * * * echo 'test' > /Desktop/test.txt
```

Also, if I am in the directory and I do "`php writer.php`" it works as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was quite stupid of me and yes, silly at its best.

The file was being output at root, and to verify, I did check `cd ~/`.

There it was, my file.